# socket.io switch between localhost & server

Tags: socket.io

I am running socket.io  on node.js on a local Mac machine.

I have setup port forwarding

I am using the following code:

```
socket = io.connect('XXX.XXX.137.143:1337');

socket.on('connect_failed', function(){
$.jGrowl('Connection Failed');

});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
$.jGrowl('disconnected');

});
    socket.on('connect', function () { 
   $.jGrowl('We are connected ' );

});
```

The IP address is my router IP address. This all works as expected.

However if I run the app on the same network as the router it fails to connect. It needs :

```
socket = io.connect('localhost'); // or the ip of the machine.
```

How do I determine I am on the same network as the machine and switch the IP setting ?

I tried:

```
if (location.hostname === "localhost" || location.hostname ===   "192.168.1.1")
{$.jGrowl("It's a local client!");
var IPaddress = 'http://192.168.1.6:1337';}
else {var IPaddress = '92.12.137.143:1337';
$.jGrowl("It's a remote client!")
}
```

This works locally but fails on another network that has IP = 192.168.1.1.

Cheers

Steve Warby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first attempt a connection to the public IP address and, if that fails, then attempt to connect locally.  Here's one way to do that:

```js
let socket = io.connect('http://92.12.137.143:1337');
socket.on('connect_error', handleNoConnect);
socket.on('connect_timeout', handleNoConnect);
socket.on('connect', onConnect);

function handleNoConnect() {
    console.log("No connection to http://92.12.137.143:1337");
    socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.6:1337');
    socket.on('connect_error', handleNoConnect2);
    socket.on('connect_timeout', handleNoConnect2);
    socket.on('connect', onConnect);
}

function handleNoConnect2() {
    console.log("No connection to http://192.168.1.6:1337");
    // decide what to do when you can't connect to either
}

function onConnect() {
    console.log("connected");

    // set other event handlers on a connected socket
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("disconnected");
    });
}
```

---

Or, here's a more general purpose implementation that lets you pass in an array of URLs to try connecting to and it returns a promise that will resolve with the `socket` that made the connection or reject with an appropriate error.

```
function connect(list) {
    let index = 0;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function next() {
            if (index < list.length) {
                let url = list[index++];
                let doneThis = false;
                let socket = io.connect(url);
                socket.on('connect_error', handleNoConnect);
                socket.on('connect_timeout', handleNoConnect);
                socket.on('connect', () => {
                    // set property on socket object that tells you 
                    //   which URL it connected to
                    socket._url = url;
                    resolve(socket);
                });

                function handleNoConnect() {
                    if (!doneThis) {
                        doneThis = true;
                        console.log("No connection to " + url);
                        // try next item in the list
                        next();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                reject(new Error("No connections succeeded"));
            }
        }
        if (!list || !list.length) {
            reject(new Error("Must pass array of URLs to connect()"));
            return;
        }
        next();
    });
}

connect(['http://92.12.137.143:1337', 'http://192.168.1.6:1337']).then(socket => {
    // connected here
    console.log("connected to " + socket._url);

    // configure event handlers on the connected socket object here
    socket.on('xxx', ...);
}).catch(err => {
    // all connections failed here
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Fixed a typo and added protection against more than one error being emitted on the same socket (probably not needed, but doing it to be safe).